# Which is the better translation

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I've come up with a neat little saying and I'd like to translate it into Latin, I've come across two different translations so far but am unsure which is the most accurate.
The saying is "No sympathy from the dead" or "there is no sympathy from the dead" either works.
And the two translations I've found are: "Non misericordiam a mortuis" and "Nulla misericordia a mortuis"
I'd like to know which is the most accurate translation?

Answer (score 6):

> Non misericordiam a mortuis

It lacks a verb, so it feels grammatically wrong with the accusative being there.

> Nulla misericordia a mortuis

This is better. 'No compassion from the dead'. It lacks the verb but it is easy to fill in *exoptatur* or similar.

Further ideas:

*Mei mortuos non miseret.* 'The dead don't feel compassion towards me.'

*Mortui non miserentur.* (See discussion below.)

*Mei mortuos non miserescit.* 'The dead don't show compassion to me.'

*Mortui non miserantur.* 'The dead don't show compassion.'

Comment: I agree with your appropriate suggestions. By the way, _miserantur_ in your last example should be replaced by _miserentur_ (2nd conj.).  As for the ellipsis, I agree that no verb is necessary in _Nulla misericordia a mortuis_ . I'd expect the elliptical verb there be a bit "lighter" (i.e. more "copulative"?) than _exoptatur_.

Comment: There are two verbs *miseror* 1st conj. which my example uses, and *misereo* (whence *misereor*) 2nd conj. Is there a huge semantic difference between those two? I agree that *exoptatur* is a bit too bombastic for the occasion. Maybe *datur*?

Comment: My intuition is that the use of _miserentur_ is more directly related to that of the previous example (_miseret_). So I'd go for _miserentur_ to express a more direct parallelism between _Mei mortuos non miseret_ and _Mortui non miserentur_: both are stative verbs with the resultative suffix _-e-_. Note also that _misereor_ is intransitive, whereas _miseror_ is transitive. Here is an article (in Spanish; NB: abstract in English) that deals with their syntactic and subtle semantic differences: https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/CFCL/article/view/43564/41196